# CMD.exe consumes all the CPU, blocking other CMD.exe to execute

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, db2, cmd

We have some Batch scripts (.bat) in Windows to execute the “backups” and “archive log” for the databases. These scripts are called from Tivoli periodically.

For each executed script, the process creates a sub session in order to load the DB2cmd environment, in order to execute the db2 commands and exit.

**daily.bat**

```
call db2cmd hourly.cmd
```

The content of the script is this:

**db2_job_saveddaily.cmd**

```
db2 -fE:\DB2\scripts\tmp\db2_job_savedbhourly.db2 -zE:\DB2\scripts\tmp\db2_job_savedbhourly.log 
exit
```

The content of the db2 file is (however, it is not important because it is executed correctly)

**db2_job_saveddaily.db2**

```
archive log for database ICMNLSDB
```

We are facing a problem with these scripts, and I think it is related with the *exit*. At one execution, the script freezes, and it starts to consume the whole CPU (see attached image). After this behavior, we cannot execute any other DB2 command from the CLP.
We kill all the CMD.exe and db2bp.exe processes, but the error persists.
There is nothing in the db2diag.log file, and the only solution is to restart the machine.
Probably, the CMD.exe process losses the communication with the db2bp.exe, and the exit cannot be executed. I would like to understand the origin of this problem and learn how to execute db2 processes in Windows.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming issue.  Have you opened a PMR with IBM?

Comment: The problem was in another db2cmd session where there was an infinitive loop. This created a scenario when new db2cmd session blocked because the first session used the whole CPU.

Comment: As it seems you found the problem, could you please create and answer yourself and accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our friend @AngocA seems to check into SO often but hasn't been checking this dangling question even though he did something to close it. Let's at least put his answer in here so folk know it's *CLOSED* by user. :)  Courtesy of tonight's Point Pimp. :-D

> "The problem was in another db2cmd session where there was an
>   infinitive loop. This created a scenario when new db2cmd session
>   blocked because the first session used the whole CPU. – AngocA"